# Generate matrix where each new column is a multiple of previous column

Tags: r, matrix

I begin with a single column data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(x1 = c(1,2))
```

I then wish to `cbind` `n` columns, where each new column equals the previous column's value multiplied by a constant `g`. For `n = 2` and `g = .05`, the result would be:

```
ans <- data.frame(x1 = c(1,2), x2 = c(1.05, 2.10), x3 = c(1.1025, 2.205))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why use a data frame? Matrix is a better structure.

```
n <- 2
g <- 0.05
x0 <- c(1, 2)
f <- (1 + g) ^ (0:n)
tcrossprod(x0, f)

#     [,1] [,2]   [,3]
#[1,]    1 1.05 1.1025
#[2,]    2 2.10 2.2050
```

Em... looks like we are computing balance for different savings and interest rates...